# insert multiple records from a single record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert multiple records into a table based on multiple values found in a single text field retrieved from a select statement. Currently I am using an `INSERT INTO and SELECT` statement where by each record in the select statement forces an `INSERT INTO`. However, I need to be able to insert multiple records, as opposed to 1, based on multiple values I parse out of a string of text. Here's bascially what I need to do:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
Select personid, name, contacts, status
```

- Parse contacts
- Determine the number of contacts in the string (see contacts string below)
- Insert 1 record per contact.

The logic should be something like this:

```
do while
insert
end

From tableB
```

The contacts field is `varchar`, and can have 3 different contacts listed in the field as follows:

```
contacts = 'Jim phone 333-222-1111, John 777-888-9999, Joe 444-555-6666"
```

I need to insert a record for each contact listed in the string - `Jim, John, and Joe`.
I'm having trouble clearly explaining this so please let me know if more information is required.

I'm using MS SQL 2012.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Have a look at [Split string by comma in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999631/split-string-by-comma-in-sql-server-2008).. which will help you to get started!!!